# How to place input value in arrays c++?

Tags: c++

New to c++. I want to take the input values in `scoreCurrent` and place them into different arrays depending on whether they're above the average or below the average. I tried looking for solutions from different websites and youtube but none worked so far. How do I do this?

I apologize if my whole code is a mess and thank you in advance.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     //  student count
    int students, upperLimit;

    cout<<"Enter no. of students: ";
    cin>>students;

     //  upper limit
    do
    {
        cout<<"Enter the upper limit: ";
        cin>>upperLimit;
        if(upperLimit<5)
        {
            cout<<"Invalid upper limit."<<endl;
            continue;
        }
            break;
    }while(true);

     //  student scores
    int scoreCurrent, scoreTotal;
    float average=0;
    int belowAve(students), aboveAve(students);

    for(int index=1; index<=students; index++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter score for student no. "<<index<<": ";
        cin>>scoreCurrent; //  take this and place it into an array

         //  condition invalid
        if(scoreCurrent>upperLimit || scoreCurrent<0)
        {
            int current=index-1;
            cout<<"Invalid score."<<endl;
            index=current;
            scoreCurrent=0;
        }

        scoreTotal+=scoreCurrent;
        average=(float) scoreTotal/(float) students;


        if(scoreCurrent>average)
        {
            // scoreCurrent values are placed in belowAve array;
        }

        if(scoreCurrent>average)
        {
            //  scoreCurrent values are placed in aboveAve array;
        }
    }

     //  display
    cout<<"Average: "<<average<<endl;
    cout<<"Scores above or equal average: "<<belowAve<<endl;
    cout<<"\nScores below average: "<<aboveAve<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are no arrays in your code. _"How to place input value in arrays"_ First step: Create arrays.

Comment: The first things will be creating arrays.[`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) may be better.

Comment: `belowAve` and `aboveAve` are ints, not arrays, and even if they were you don't have any code that attempts to place anything in them. I would suggest trying to make them `std::vector`s and then it's as simple as calling `push_back` on the appropriate container. Although the code for displaying a container is a bit more complicated than what you have.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use an array?.  A common solution for this type of thing in c++ is to declare a `std::vector<int>` for storage and do a `pushback()` to append it to the back of it

Comment: Consider using C++ casts as opposed to C casts (e.g. `static_cast<float>()` against `(float)`).

Comment: There is another big point: Currently you are using a running average, e.g. 3 students with scores 5, 6, 7. After the first loop iteration the average is 5 / 3. After the second loop iteration the average is (5+6) / 3. After the third iteration the average is (5+6+7) / 3. You fix this you have to first read and store the all scores and calculate the sum of scores. Then calculate the average. Then split all students into two arrays / vectors.

Comment: _New to C++_ → you need a book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that `scorecurrent` is an array (and `index` the offset in `scorecurrent`)? If you think that this will work

```
std::cin >> scoreCurrent;
```

then the problems are:

1. where in `scorecurrent` will the input be placed (you don't use `index`)?
2. (if you want to give scores for all indices) when does the input stop?

Apart from the argument that a vector is better (which it is, because you don't need to specify its size and can just `push_back()`) I think [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52384783/1793968) is a very elegant way to solve your problem.

It uses a lambda function to iterate over all elements of a (fixed-sized) array. There is also another, more traditional solution where the `>>` operator of `std::cin` is overloaded for arguments of array types.