# Taking Input an array in C++ using cin directly by operator overloading

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operator-overloading, variable-length-array

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>


template<typename T, size_t Size>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, T (&arr)[Size])
{
    std::for_each(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), [&in](auto& elem) {
        in >> elem;
    });

    return in;
}


void solve()
{
  int n, q;
  cin>>n>>q;
  int pre[n], a[n];
  memset(pre, 0, sizeof(pre));
  cin >> a;  // this statement is not working giving compilation error as:-
 "no operator ">>" matches these operands C/C++(349)
a.cpp(167, 7): operand types are: std::istream >> long long [n]"

}

#undef int
int main()
{
  ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
  cin.tie(NULL);
  cout.tie(NULL);
  int t = 1;
  cin >> t;
  while (t--)
    solve();
  return (int)0;
}
```

The above written cin code in the solve function for taking an array input using operator overloading is not working, why so? I am trying to use the operator overloading for input stream operator cin and trying to use it to input an array and then process it over. So overall reducing time by cin cin ... a lot.
I have taken reference from [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52384343/how-do-i-use-cin-for-an-array#:%7E:text=For%20more%20modern%20C%2B%2B%20approach%3A%20%23include%20%3Calgorithm%3E%20and,or%20you%20could%20use%20it%20as%20operator%3E%3E%20overload) .

Comment: `pre` and `a` are not arrays. They are Variable Length Arrays, entirely different thing that's not even part of C++ (some compilers unfortunately accept it as an extension).

Comment: Time to learn about `std::vector`. As a bonus this gets rid of junk like `memset()`.

Comment: PSA: In C++ prefer `nullptr` to C's typeless `NULL`.

Comment: Unrelated: Seeing `#include <iostream>` and `#include <algorithm>` alongside `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` strongly suggest that you know not what `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` is for. [Here's some reading on that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/4581301). It's often an unforced error, so prefer to include the headers you need, no more and no less.

Comment: Somewhere out there there must be a `using namespace std` in order for the compiler to get as far as it did. [Prefer not to use it as well](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/4581301). When you combine `using namespace std;` with `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` you're really ramping up the odds of a negative user interaction with the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are using variable length arrays

```
  int n, q;
  cin>>n>>q;
  int pre[n], a[n];
```

Variable length arrays are not a standard C++ feature.

The variable `n` is not a compile time constant. It may not be used as a non-type template argument.

Instead use standard container `std::vector`.

With vector you could use just range-based for loop to enter values. If nevertheless you want to implement your approach with the overloaded operator then it can look the following way as shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
std::istream &operator >>( std::istream &in, std::vector<T> &v )
{
    std::for_each( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ), 
        [&in]( auto &elem ) 
        {
            in >> elem;
        } );

    return in;
}

int main()
{
    size_t n = 5;
    std::vector<int> v( n );

    std::cout << "Enter " << n << " values: ";
    std::cin >> v;

    for (const auto &elem : v)
    {
        std::cout << elem << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
Enter 5 values: 1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
```

Also pay attention to that the casting the integer constant `0` of the type `int` to the type `int` in the return statement

```
return (int)0;
```

does not make sense. Just write

```
return 0;
```

Or you may even remove the return statement.

And this header `<bits/stdc++.h>` is not a standard C++ header and is redundant in your program. Remove it and instead of it include header `<iterator>`.

And as there is no using directive and nor using declaration then use the qualifier name in this statement

```
cin >> a;
```

like

```
std::cin >> a;
```

And it is unclear what thsi directive

```
#undef int
```

is doing in your program,