# when I use cin>>char ch[] ,why does it say Invalid operands to binary expression ('istream' and 'char *') in my Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, cin

I define an array s[1000] and I use the cin to input the string,but when I use the cin>>s+1;
the compiler makes an error:Invalid operands to binary expression ('istream' and 'char *')

I am I beginner in c++,
what's. wrong with my code?
I want to read the char element from the Index 1 so I wanna to use (s+1)

Comment: Why `cin>> s+1` instead of just `cin >> s` ? Also see dupe [How do I use cin for an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52384343/how-do-i-use-cin-for-an-array)

Comment: Also post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: TLDR, you should not even be using a "C" style array for this. E.g. to read 10 values use   `std::vector<int> values(10); for(int& value : values) std::cin >> value;`.

Comment: Where are you learning C++ from?

Comment: `s+1` causes [array decay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/4581301). You can't add 1  to an array, that's nonsensical, but you can add 1 to a pointer. Reading into a `char` pointer used to be legal before C++20, but it was soooooo easy for the user to abuse it that it just wasn't funny. A pointer has no clue how much it points at, so `>>` had no clue where to stop. User could just hold down a key and watch the array overflow. You had to be a fool to read directly into a pointer with `>>`, so it was removed.

Comment: so it's removed after C++ 20

Comment: @jenojeff [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)